# Orientation on image thumbnails and how programs interpret it?

Tags: thumbnails

I took a photo with my iPhone of a package of bread, oriented in landscape. I then copy-pasted it to iOS-Mail (the only way to get un-resized photos sent via email), and emailed it to myself.

In the gmail preview, the image is oriented correctly. That is, the bread labels display text correctly.

When I downloaded the image to my desktop, I opened the image in Paint.NET, the image as rotated counter-clockwise 90 degrees.

I rotated the image in paint.net 90degrees clockwise, resized it, then saved it.

I emailed this photo to a friend, and in the gmail preview it now shows oriented 90CW, and the image preview in windows shows it as 90degrees counter-clockwise.

If I open the image, or upload the image, it is oriented properly.

**So why are thumbnails oriented incorrectly, and how does software interpret the orientation to display the image?**

Here are the thumbnails, windows on the left, gmail on the right. Same image.

[image: rotations]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options for software -- you can either orientate the file in the right direction, or you can store meta-information that stores the information to allow for automatic correction. Not all software supports the automatic correction, and it is most likely one of these cases that you've spotted.